# Switch is not working in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Switch in react router dom is not working!

problem seems to arrive when rendering the AddTodo and Todos element!

Tried replacing the switch with route but it still  does not reem to render anything

```
return (
<>
  <Router>
    <Header title="Task" />
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
        return (
          <>
            <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
            <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
          </>
        )
      }} >
      </Route>

      <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
    </Routes>


    <Footer />
  </Router>
</>
```

);

Comment: which version of `react-router` are you using ?

Comment: its 6.8.1  version of react router dom

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

use BrowserRouter for last version (v6)

```
return (
<>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header title="Task" />
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={() => {
        return (
          <>
            <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
            <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
          </>
        )
      }} >
      </Route>

      <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
    </Routes>


    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
</>
```

Comment: it still doesnot seem to work !!

Comment: it does not render out the addtodo and todos component .. while the about component is getting  rendered!

Comment: @rishav I edit code and change  render props to element, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when i did  this !

```
return (

  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header title="Task" />
    
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path ="/" element={
        <>
        <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo}/>
        <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
        </>
      }
      />
      <Route exact path ="/" element={<Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />} />
      

      <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
    </Routes>


    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

);